# While loop with PhantomJS?

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

I have code that is scraping a website for certain data, though I would like to expand it to many websites (though maintaining the same code). Could I just use a while loop with an array of the links (I'm assuming same syntax as JS)? If not, how else could I go about this?

```js
var webPage = require('webpage');
var page = webPage.create();

page.open('http://shop.advanceautoparts.com/p/purolator-classic-air-filter-a24278/5792304-P?navigationPath=L1*14934&zoneAssigned=1&prefStoredSet=1&prefZC=07047', function(status) {             
    page.sendEvent('mousemove', 1, 1);
    page.sendEvent('click');
    page.sendEvent('click');
    setTimeout(function(){
        var fetchData = page.evaluate(function(){
            return document.getElementById("add2Cart_1").className;
        });
        sort(fetchData);
        page.close();
    }, 3000);
});

function sort(string) {
    if (string == "button yellow add2Cart disabled") {
        console.log("Out of Stock");
    } else {
        console.log("In Stock");
    }
}`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Could I just use a while loop with an array of the links (I'm assuming same syntax as JS)?

Yes.  It's just JavaScript.  Be aware that you'll be doing them all in parallel if you don't block until each page is done.

Comment: when I try to implement a simple while loop it fails to recognize the setTimeout, any suggestions?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by, "fails to recognize the setTimeout".

Comment: Rather than waiting 3 seconds (from my setTimeout function), it skips through all of the code and doesn't render the page at all for any link.

Comment: What do you mean by, "skips through all of the code"?  I can't guess at what your code does... you should post a new question with your updated code.